How to get the SIM card details from the iPhone using my iOS App?
A SIM card contains ICCID (International Circuit Card ID). The ICCID is unique in the world. I need my app get the ICCID of the SIM card that is in the iPhone. Does anyone know whether it is possible, and if possible, how to do?
i am using below code.
let networkInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
        if let carrier = networkInfo.serviceSubscriberCellularProviders?.values.first {
            print("Carrier Name: \(carrier.carrierName ?? "Unknown")")
            print("Mobile Country Code: \(carrier.mobileCountryCode ?? "Unknown")")
            print("Mobile Network Code: \(carrier.mobileNetworkCode ?? "Unknown")")
            print("ISO Country Code: \(carrier.isoCountryCode ?? "Unknown")")
            print("Allows VOIP: \(carrier.allowsVOIP)")
        } else {
            print("No carrier information available")
        }

and receiving default values
Carrier Name: --
Mobile Country Code: 65535
Mobile Network Code: 65535
ISO Country Code: --
Allows VOIP: true


It is not possible
